# SQL Top N per item group and M for each user

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, greatest-n-per-group, ranking

Sample Data:

| user_id | item_type | item_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | A | 10 |
| 11 | A | 9 |
| 11 | A | 2 |
| 11 | B | 4 |
| 11 | B | 1 |
| 11 | C | 2 |
| 12 | A | 2 |
| 12 | B | 4 |
| 12 | B | 1 |
| 12 | D | 1 |

Desired Output:

| user_id | item_type | item_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | A | 10 |
| 11 | B | 4 |
| 11 | C | 2 |
| 12 | A | 2 |
| 12 | B | 4 |
| 12 | D | 1 |

For each user, I want the top item by item count within each item type they have. So For user 11, they should get the top record for item A, the top record for item B, and the top record for c. I'm a little stuck. I think it should be a two-fold ranking problem, but most examples I can find are selecting for the top user/item, regardless of item type, but I want the top item of each item type per user.

```
select * from (
    select user_id, 
           item_type,
           item_count, 
           row_number() over (partition by user order by item_count desc) as item_rank 
    from table) ranks
where item_rank <= 2;
```

this just gets the top items per user, but I want the top items per item type per user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to partition by user *and* item here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, item_type
                                   ORDER BY item_count DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable t
)

SELECT user_id, item_type, item_count
FROM cte
WHERE rn <= 2
ORDER BY user_id, item_type;
```

Answer (score 0):

This can achieved without using a Window function.

You can group by `user_id` and `item_type`, then get the `Max` on `item_count`.

```
DECLARE @table TABLE
(
    user_id int,
    item_type char,
    item_count int
)

insert into @table
values
(11,    'A',    10),
(11,    'A',    9 ),
(11,    'A',    2 ),
(11,    'B',    4 ),
(11,    'B',    1 ),
(11,    'C',    2 ),
(12,    'A',    2 ),
(12,    'B',    4 ),
(12,    'B',    1 ),
(12,    'D',    1 )

select * from @table


select
    user_id, item_type, Max(item_count)
from @table
    group by user_id, item_type
order by user_id
```